# What is the sephardi equivalent to the Mishna Berura?

Tags: halacha, product-recommendation, jewish-books, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, mishnah-berurah

What is the sephardi equivalent to the Mishna Berura ? Do some sephardim follow the mishna berura ?

Comment: I doubt they need one. The shulchan aruch is sephardi as afaik, and the the mishneh brurah is an ashkenazi gloss on it (to I guess be read with it), to account for the ashkenazi version of the customs.

Answer (score 6):

I think כף החיים might be the best analogy. [example page](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14418&st=&pgnum=20&hilite=/)

Comment: Thanks. Maybe the Ben Ich Hay too?

Comment: The Ben Ish Hai is certainly a well respected Sephardi posek, but his work doesn't have the same scope that the kaf hachaim or mishnah berurah have. The Ben Ish Hai focused on a selection of halachot he thought were important. The MB comments on all of the Shulchan Aruch Orach Haim and the Kaf Hachaim covers all of Orach Haim and parts of Yoreh Deah. The Kaf HaChaim is a better parallel.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if some sephardim follow MB?

Comment: Kaf hachaim. Ben ish chai was more like their version of the kitzur shulchan aruch. I say 'was' because in recent decades there has been a push by the sfardi gadol hador to move away from these sfarim, claiming that their psakim leaned towards and relied too much on ashkenazi poskim. In fact he wrote an an entire set of sfarim made to look like a supercommentary on the ben ish chai, but in reality he replaced and negated all the psakim that were too ashkenized.

Comment: @user6591 I'm not following...."_In fact **he** wrote an an entire set of sfarim_" ....who is "he"?

Comment: @Shokket I didn't want to say because people get offended when a tremendous genious is called out as a bigot who allows his personal affiliations to sway his halachic decisions. I'll try once more to drop a hint. The specific work I reffered to is called 'Halichos Olam'. But his other works carry on in the same vein.

Answer (score 2):

[Mishna Berura Tiferet Hamizrach](http://seforimheadquarters.com/index.php?id_product=6111&controller=product) is a project that has started a few years ago. So far there is one volume on Chanuka. There is a team of Talmidei Chachomim working on it and they anticipate having the entire Mishna Berura over the coming years. This includes the following Sefardi Poskim.

פרי חדש, ברכי יוסף ומחזיק ברכה, מאמר מרדכי, מטה יהודה, שולחן גבוה, רוח חיים , יפה ללב, שדי חמד, זכרונות אליהו, שו"ת רב פעלים, בן איש חי, תורה לשמה, כף החיים, שואל ונשאל, שמחת כהן, ישכיל עבדי, שו"ת תבואות שמ"ש ושמש ומגן, שו"ת יביע אומר ויחוה דעת, חזון עובדיה, אור לציון, ילקוט יוסף, תורת המועדים, שו"ע המקוצר, שופר בציון, קדוש בציון, ופסקי הגר"מ מאזוז שליט"א.
ומאות פסקים המופיעים בעשרות ספרי שותי"ם נוספים, מהם:
שו"ת הרדב"ז, אבקת רוכל, גנת ורדים, בית דוד, יוסף אומץ, שער יוסף, חיים שאל, זרע אמת, קול אליהו, בית יהודה, שמש צדקה, מעט מים, חקרי לב, לב חיים, חקקי לב, פעולת צדיק, ויאמר יצחק, כפי אהרון, אור לי, מים חיים, תפילה למשה ועוד.

Answer (score 2):

Yalkut Yosef. It is an authoritative, contemporary work of Halakha, providing a detailed explanation of the Shulchan Aruch.